# how to convert UITextfield into hex value

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, hex

I am wanting to xor (^) two values and pass the result to an integer. Both values are being passed in from UITextFields, the first like so ...

```
NSString *recieveCode = myCode.text;
int tempCode = [recieveCode intValue];
```

however the second value coming in needs to be converted to hex.... which I am not sure how to do.. (obviously I will have to do some checking at some point to make sure all characters in the string conform to hex format) but for now I am just trying to figure out how to cast the text in the uitextfield is hex format so I can try ^ the two values together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned int intValue;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];
[scanner scanHexInt:&intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int  tempInt = 0;
NSString *recieveCode = myCode.text;
int tempCode = [recieveCode intValue];
NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:recieveCode];
[scanner scanHexInt:&tempInt];
```

Comment: thank you, this worked perfectly. however, because I am mixing NSNumber and int, I need to convert both to int before I XOR the two values together...

Comment: You can just leave out the last step in the example above that needlessly converts the int into an NSNumber. Just use the `tempInt`, it's an ordinary int.

Comment: yeah sorry, I forgot you were going to to bitwise operations on it, you wouldn't want to use an NSNumber for that, will edit.